webix datatable textfilter compare method has value undefined
I am trying something like this:
This is my datatable
Batch0 = [                 // common columns
    { id: "_index", header: "", width: 45, template: function () { return arguments[4] + 1 } },
    { id: 'fsName', editor: 'text', header: ["Fs Name",{content:'textFilter',compare:reComp}], tooltip: false, width: 180, cssFormat: bgColorFuseDiff, template: fmtDiffObj },
  ];

and this is my reComp method
function reComp(value, filter) {
  console.log(value); //coming as undefined
  console.log(filter);
  try {
      return RegExp(filter, "i").test(value);
  }    
  catch(e) {
    return false;
  }    
}

and in reComp, the value is always coming as undefined. filter is printing what text I input into the filter in the datable header.
Please help me on why value is coming as undefined.

Well, it's hard to tell, too few details. Could you, please, show the data for the table? Take this snippet https://snippet.webix.com/bhgb7gow , change it to reproduce the situation and then I bet it would be clear what's going on.
